# update_checkout after each product is added to the cart

Tags: jquery, ajax, woocommerce

An additional set of recommended products is displayed on the checkout page. The problem is that when you add products to the cart, the page itself does not update the data. I tried to add an event that would update the data when you click on the "add to cart" button, but something is not working correctly.

I tried this:

```
jQuery( '.add_to_cart_button' ).on( 'click', function($) {
  $( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps someone will need it. Just added a trigger timeout so that products can be added to the cart in time)

```
jQuery( '.add_to_cart_button' ).on( 'click', function() {
function update_checkout_trigger_init () {
  jQuery( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
} setTimeout(update_checkout_trigger_init,500);
});
```